# How to show file size of featured image?

Tags: images, featured-post

How to show file size of featured image in post on single.php?

For example:
File size of featured image is: xx kb/Mb

I need size of featured "full" rezolution, also file size of "medium" resolution would be great?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Following function calculate file size, just you need change '/myfile/image.jpg' with your featured image variable.

```
   <?php 
    function file_size($url){ 
        $size = filesize($url); 
        if($size >= 1073741824){ 
            $fileSize = round($size/1024/1024/1024,1) . 'GB'; 
        }elseif($size >= 1048576){ 
            $fileSize = round($size/1024/1024,1) . 'MB'; 
        }elseif($size >= 1024){ 
            $fileSize = round($size/1024,1) . 'KB'; 
        }else{ 
            $fileSize = $size . ' bytes'; 
        } 
        return $fileSize; 
    }


    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );

   //echo file_size('/myfile/image.jpg');
     echo file_size($feat_image);  
    ?>
```

And check out [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

Comment: Try `size_format()`.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to replace '/myfile/image.jpg' with current post featured image?

Comment: I updated code. I didn't test it.

Comment: I tested it. I get nothing with that. Maybe to try with `$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');`, or something else?